# hibernate-spatial unresolved dependencies postgis-jdbc;1.5.3: not found

Tags: hibernate, scala, lift

I am installing hibernate spatial, following are the steps in the documentation from the official site:

http://www.hibernatespatial.org/tutorial-hs4.html

The problem is with the libraries' dependence

Why not find the library:

postgis-jdbc: jar: 1.5.3: compile

Look for the version of this library on the official site:

http://postgis.refractions.net/download/

But not available

The message displayed on the terminal is as follows:

```
[warn]    http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/postgis/postgis-jdbc/1.5.3/postgis-jdbc-1.5.3.jar
[warn]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]          ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]          :: org.postgis#postgis-jdbc;1.5.3: not found
[warn]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[info] 
[info] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this dependency

Thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the latest available version of postgis-jdbc in maven central repository is 1.3.3.
Unfortunately, none of the three additional repositories that are declared in hibernate-spatial tutorial contain version 1.5.3 of postgis-jdbc (highest version is 1.5.2 available in repo http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository/).

Version 1.5.3 is not listed on the postgis download page, however you still can download it here: http://postgis.refractions.net/download/postgis-1.5.3.tar.gz

A pragmatic approach would be to build the library yourself (described in postgis-1.5.3/java/jdbc/README) and add it manually to your local maven repository (please see Maven's documentation - I'd like to provide the URL but due to my current SO reputation I cannot post more than two URLs per answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also tell your build system to ignore the transitive dependency and then declare the version you need explicitly. Not sure which build system lift uses, but here's how I did it with SBT in Play Framework:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  [...]
  "org.postgis" % "postgis-jdbc" % "1.5.2",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-spatial" % "4.0-M1" exclude("org.postgis", "postgis-jdbc")  
)
```

You also have to add the hibernate spatial repo to have access to version `1.5.2`:

```
resolvers += (
    "Hibernate Spatial Repository" at "http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository" 
)
```

I learned this using [this tutorial](http://cnokello.blogspot.com/2012/08/hibernate-spatial-4x-with-spring-31x.html), which shows how to do the same thing using Maven.